# upload and attach a photo to a facebook note

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I am trying to attach a photo to a facebook note with the following code

```
$attachment = array(                                                                              
 'message' => 'photo caption',                                                                    
 'subject' => 'photo subject',                                                                    
 'id' => $note_id                                                                                 
);                                                                                                

$attachment[basename($file_path)] = '@' . realpath($file_path);                                   
$result = $facebook->api('/notes', 'POST', $attachment);
```

which generates an error code: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Requires extended permission: create_note

note_id is holding a correct note_id which is created above with the following code:

```
$note = $facebook->api('/notes', 'POST', array(                                                   
  'access_token' => $token,                                                                       
  'subject' => 'subject',                                                                         
  'message' => 'message'                                                                          
));                                                                                               
$note_id = $note{'id'};
```

facebook note api reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/ doesn't provide much details on this task. plz help.